# Voxelizer and Textrues in Blender

Tags: texturing, uv

There are two 3d models from the sketchfab. I'm trying to convert them to voxels using an online voxelizer.
In the first case, when I use Lightning McQueen, everything is fine, he prompts me to add a texture.
In the second case, when I use Doc Hudson, it does not offer to add a texture and writes that several textures need to be combined into one.
I can not figure out where and how exactly to do this in blender. Please tell me. Thank you

I use this online voxelizer: https://drububu.com/miscellaneous/voxelizer/?out=vox

This McQueen model: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/lightning-mcqueen-20512a1065ce4d6f869b348bfbf72bb1

This Doc Hudson model: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/doc-hudson-600d9157d8a14ba0bce47d8f4309a921

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am also using the same tool as I had to make voxel art for my client. So the solution is that you have to bake different images textures or materials (pbr/shaders) into single image so that the online tool can process it. The tool allows one image as a texture it does not support multiple ones. So you can use different addons to bake all of your materials(which are currently applied on your models).
If you are a blender user you can use simple bake addon (you can download it from internet for free too, do some research)
I wish you will be able to solve this, if not send me your models I will do it for you.
Peace, Out!

Comment: hi bro, huge big for the answer. I still can't deal with this addon simple back. Do you have the opportunity to record a video, how to use it, please? Or maybe on YouTube there is a guide specifically for my solution to the issue. I can not find. Also here is the optimal model, I can't add two textures to one. Maybe you can do it?

https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/optimus-prime-8a37b8485f1c4f20b8a318adce82357b

Comment: bro, give me your contacts in instant messengers, for example, in Telegram, if you want, I will pay you for the work, I urgently need to make several models, I can’t figure it out myself. Thank you

Comment: Hey there, Sorry I couldn't check back on the site. I am on Discord with username sanaullahamzah. Hit me there and happy to help

Comment: Hey the addons didnt worked well so I did more and more research and have successfully baked your optimus prime model materials into one, hope to hear back from you!

Comment: @ALex I have baked your McQueen as well and also have used the voxelizer, everything is working fine

Comment: https://we.tl/t-gTUfvNQSL3
have a look here

Comment: Hello, yes, I had problems with the optimus, using the simple bake addon, the textures drove over each other. Apparently, you need to build the parameters differently, unfortunately, I did not find the answer myself. I sent a friend request on discord. I'm waiting for you there. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: hey yes accepted already